# Updating EXIF info in image files

Tags: c#, gdi+, exif

I need to update EXIF info in a lot of .png files (tens of thousands of hires pictures) and I wonder if there is some (not too complicated and documented) way that I can do that without opening (decompressing the whole image) and then re-save it (compressing it again)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the .Net GDI+ image format support is very patchy.

Consider ImageMagick. There is a .Net wrapper for it.

- http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Also consider ExifTool:

- http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/