# How to read and modify latitude and longitude data of jpg file in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, jpeg, exif

I'm working in vc++ 08. I need to read EXIF data of particular JPG file and modify it. In that mostly I need to read Latitude and Longitude data of JPG file and modify it. I searched for library that can give me access to EXIF data of JPG file but after all efforts I ended up here. I don't think there is any header file that can give me access of EXIF data of JPG file in vc++. Please help me out. Any examples will be appreciated. Or referce to any library for read and modify EXIF data of JPG file also appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192480/updating-exif-info-in-image-files

Comment: @rkosegi, those are for c# not for c++. But anyway thanks for link.

Comment: No, http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php is C++ library and Exiftool is in perl.Just question was taged as C#

Comment: @rkosegi Magick++ does not provide access of GPS EXIF data of jpg file. So still not getting solution.

Comment: @rkosegi I've used exiv2.exe, and it gives all functionality but every time I used that tool command prompt splash on monitor. Is there any other way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Finding the info you're after is not so difficult in straight C code. You start by searching the file for the EXIF marker (APP1 = FFE1) and within that, search for the EXIF IFD tag and then search that IFD for the GPS coordinates. Can be done in around 100-200 lines of C with no external libraries.

Comment: @BitBank any example of your saying? Because I'm new to parse JPG files. Or any link?

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for you. Do some "Googling" for JPEG APP1 marker, TIFF IFD structure and EXIF TIFF tags. Here's a good starting point:
http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/gps.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.

Use [exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org) library. It gives all access to exif data of image file. You can read and modify exif data very easily using this.

And more importantly it is free and open source.

Detailed usage : http://linux.die.net/man/1/exiv2

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Adobe XMP toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html)
It can work with EXIF GPS data - not just XMP and is native C++